# Recent iPhone PNG Screenshot cgImage is black

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I add an image from my gallery to my video compiling app with this code :

```
// add image
let overlayLayerLogo: CALayer = CALayer()
overlayLayerLogo.contents = params.logo.cgImage
let imageSize = params.logo.size
overlayLayerLogo.frame = CGRect(x: 30, y: 30, width: imageSize.width, height: imageSize.height)
overlayLayerLogo.masksToBounds = true
parentLayer.addSublayer(overlayLayerLogo)
```

It works well in most cases but not for the screenshots taken by an iPhone 8 :

```
iPhone 6S Plus - Picture taken by the camera => OK
iPhone 6S Plus - Screenshot => OK
iPhone 6S Plus - Screenshot converted to JPEG => OK
iPhone 8 - Picture taken by the camera => OK
iPhone 8 - Screenshot => KO : The image is all black
iPhone 8 - Screenshot converted to JPEG => OK
```

Is there a specific format i am not aware of?

I tried to change the picture format settings (HEIF/JPEG) but it does not change anything for the screenshots

Comment: Can you please add screenshot of the iphone 8 issue you are using?

Comment: Here is [the file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1nwNoSfMjkyA-d_SR3hAGkVtXea-QGSc1/view?usp=sharing) used

Comment: I am able to see the screenshot of the notes clearly. But i am not seeing any screen which is black